# how do you manage argocd users from terraform code or platform as code?

Tags: terraform, argocd, pac

How to set terraform code to be able to update argocd-cm and argocd-rbac-cm for new user without go to argocd ui.(turning argocd user management as plateform as code).

Tried to pull the current argocd-cm and argocd-rbac-cm files, updated them but having data load error when reconnected to argocd ui.

Comment: You'd need to share with us the exact error message and the configmaps content.

Comment: Also note that ArgoCD can manage itself. This is a common pattern. Install it manually first time and then let it automanahe itself through GitOps.